# issue calling JavaScript function from PHP

Tags: php, javascript

basically I am trying to call a javascript function from my PHP and I am using code I know works in other situations however here is it not and I am at a loss as to why?

It may be something stupid as I have been staring at this screen for a long time :)

here is where I call the function:

```
if(isset($test_details['done_test'])){
    echo "getting here";
    echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>user_error();</SCRIPT>";
}
```

I successfully get 'getting here' printed however it does not call the JS function.

javascript function:

```
   function user_error(){
   document.write("working");
        //alert("User has already taken this test. Your are being redirected...");
        //setTimeout("window.location='home_student.php'",3000);
   }
```

The commented it what I do eventually want it to do.

Could anyone please shed some light.

Many thanks,

@Crimson - Here is what I tried after your advice...still no luck.

javascript now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var done = "<?= $test_details['done_test'] ?>";
     if(typeof done != 'undefined'){
          $('WORKING').appendTo('#bodyArea'); // just to test
     }
});
```

Comment: remember you're not really calling it from PHP -- you're generating part of an HTML document that's than calling your JS function. Can you link to the final output document, or provide it in your question? The fact you're writing the script tag via PHP is largely irrelevant.

Comment: does the js function work when you call it in plain html?

Comment: The order of the code is important here, the latter, javascript function has to be declared **before** the call in the first code block of the generated html document. The order of your examples is so to say, incorrect ;)

Comment: Note that the [language attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) is deprecated. You should use `type="text/javascript"` instead. Can you turn on [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see if you get any JavaScript errors elsewhere?

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne, that is the issue, I am new to programming, so I didn't know this.

Comment: @buymypies, np ;) You've learned something today, that is all that is important ;)

Comment: The issue is that I want to make this check straight away on loading the page and I want to make use of javascript alert() and setTimeout()

Answer (score 2):

By echoing `<script>...</script>` with PHP, you are not going to get the browser run the JS function!

PHP only outputs the HTML file that you want to send to the browser. The browser then parses this HTML and does a multitude of things before the page is displayed to the user.

Next, the user interacts with the displayed page (or some other browser related event like 'onload' happens) and the attached JS gets called.

So, if there is some JS that you want to run at a certain time, say immediately after the browser has finished loading the page, you need to create JS in the HTML file such that there is a JS function which gets called at the page load event like this:

```
<body onload="/*do something here*/"> ... </body>
```

It is better to use JQuery or some other JS frmework to accomplish something like this though.

Comment: Anything inside a `<script>` tag is going to get executed whenever the browser encounters it while parsing the page. Moving it to an onload handler simply changes when the call happens. it may be that his user_error function hasn't been loaded yet, but fundamentally, there's nothing wrong with how he's going abou tit.

Comment: i've identified the fact that I am trying to call the function before the script has been parsed. Still I am faced with the issue I want to make this check on loading the page and make use of javascript.

Comment: @Andre: It is always better to use a framework because different browsers execute 'body onload' at different times and many times 'body onload' is called when the script hasn't been loaded. This is precisely why frameworks like Jquery have the basic 'ready' functions. All JS/JQuery code is practically written inside one such 'ready' function.

Comment: @buymypies: use Jquery - $(document).ready(function(){/*whatever*/}). See more at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Crimson: but with this, I still want to run a mysql query first to get the value I want to check, then I want to make use of the javascript/jquery.

Comment: @buymypies: That's all right. You need to understand the difference between what you are achieving with PHP and what you can achieve with JS.

Comment: but how can I use PHP to run my query and get the value and then have my JS function run on its own? doesn't using .ready() run the script before anything else?

Comment: ok. steps. 1) PHP gets called and runs SQL queries to get your data, 2) PHP script further outputs HTML and JS (anticipate what JS you will need to run later) and also outputs your data in whatever fashion you want, 3) The browser load everything and the JS you had written runs NOW.

Comment: if you look at my updated post, it shows what I have tried after reading your advice, but not working, nt sure if I am following correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the function is already defined? Perhaps you declared your function after making the function call.

Additionally, although it's not really going to matter here, the proper way to have a javascript script tag is.

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i.e. not `language="javascript"`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line you call the JS function with this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = user_error </script>' ;
```

It should solve the problem. Because at the time you are calling user_error(), the function may not have been initialized by the browser. So you'll get an error since the function could not be found.

If the function is placed in an external .js file, it's very likely that you get this error, since the external file usually takes a while to be loaded. If the function deceleration is in the same file but after where you are calling it, same thing happens.

Comment: if you look at my updated post, I changed my method to use that jquery however still no luck :S